# Getting PostgresSQL 42703 error (invalid column error)

Tags: javascript, postgresql, rest

I am working on a React project with PostgreSQL database, this is the first time I am using it, and  I am getting 42703 error on querying a particular column.

Below is the code I have written to query

```js
const getList = (userId) => {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pool.query(`SELECT items FROM public."user" where id=${userId}`, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            }
            resolve(results);
        })
    })
}
```

I have defined this getList function and then I am making an api call to call this function by passing the userId like this

```js
app.get(`/expenses`, verifySession(), async (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.session.userId;
    database.getList(userId)
        .then(response => {
            res.status(200).send(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).send(error);
        })
})
```

I even tried passing the userId directly as shown below , still it gives me the same error , which probably means I am querying in a wrong way

```js
app.get(`/expenses`, verifySession(), async (req, res) => {
    //const userId = req.session.userId;
    database.getList('17a6dea6-a63e-4da7-9910-df7eddb672e6')
        .then(response => {
            res.status(200).send(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).send(error);
        })
})
```

Only when I directly write the string in the query it works properly like this

```js
const getList = (userId) => {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pool.query(`SELECT items FROM public."user" where id='17a6dea6-a63e-4da7-9910-df7eddb672e6'`, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            }
            resolve(results);
        })
    })
}
```

Can someone please help we with what is exactly going wrong and if my syntax is correct or not ?

This is the frontend part of where I am calling the api.

```js
 function getDataForUser() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/data`)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            }).then(data => {
                console.log(data.rows[0]);
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happened because you didn't use a single quotation for string type in the query. When using `where id=${userId}` and called with **17a6dea6-a63e-4da7-9910-df7eddb672e6** converted to `where id=17a6dea6-a63e-4da7-9910-df7eddb672e6` and this make problem.

You can use two scenarios to handle it:

1. Use the single quotation for string type:

```js
const getList = (userId) => {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pool.query(`SELECT items FROM public."user" where id='${userId}'`, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            }
            resolve(results);
        })
    })
}
```

2. Use parameter binding (As default it converted type)

```js
const getList = (userId) => {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pool.query(`SELECT items FROM public."user" where id=$1`, [userId], (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            }
            resolve(results);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thankyou , that solved the query. Also I had one more doubt like I am getting the output in this form ``` [{"row":"(\"{\"\"{\\\\\"\"shopping\\\\\"\":200}\"\",\"\"{\\\\\"\"food\\\\\"\":300}\"\"}\",2000)"}]  ``` . How am supposed to use it , like what is the signifance of this slashes

Comment: What is your data type? Why it's like that?

Comment: I have 3 columns in my row , here I quering 2 of them items and budget , items is a json array and budget is numeric. I have added above the frontend code also where I am converting the response to json and then the row property is giving a output with slashes like above.

Comment: Any suggestions could be really helpful

Comment: Can you put in a query related make this output?